# Convert code by writing new function in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

Below program is working fine but same four line repeating in every function. Make that into a function, then call it directly with values. No need for vars.

```
void __fastcall TfrmMain::Num1()
{
String name = GetCurrentDir() + "\\first.exe";
if(FileExists(name))
  {
    ShellExecute(NULL, L"runas", name.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
  }
  else
  {
    Message();
  }
 }

void __fastcall Main::Num2()
{
String name = GetCurrentDir() + "\\second.exe";
if(FileExists(name))
 {
   ShellExecute(NULL, L"runas", name.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
 }
 else
 {
   Message();
 }
 }  

void __fastcall Main::Num3()
{
String name = GetCurrentDir() + "\\third.exe";
if(FileExists(name))
 {
   ShellExecute(NULL, L"runas", name.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
 }
 else
 {
   Message();
 }
 }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Is the only difference the name of the program to run? Then pass that as an argument to the one single function.

Comment: By the way, this should have been a better fit on [the code review SE site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, it's not suitable for [codereview.se], as it's asking for replacement code rather than a review of the actual code.  And it would require much more context to be reviewable, too.

Answer (score 3):

You need to write a function that takes `name` as an argument so I've included an example of how that could look.

I've removed the check if the file exists because that's not the only thing making it possible to execute it and even if the file is executable, it may still fail to execute it for a large number of reasons. Instead, just try to execute it an then investigate the return value. You need to cast it to an `int` and if that `int` is greater than 32, it was successful.

Example:

```cpp
bool __fastcall RunAs(String name) {
    name = GetCurrentDir() + "/" + name;

    auto hInst = ShellExecute(nullptr, _T("runas"), name.c_str(),
                              nullptr, nullptr, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    int rv = reinterpret_cast<int>(hInst);

    bool successful = rv > 32;

    if(not successful) {
        /*
        switch(rv) {
        case ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: // one of the many possible errors
            // do something specific to this error
            break;
        }
        */
        Message();
    }

    // Make it possible for the calling functions to take action
    // if running the program failed:
    return successful; 
}
```

Then you could change the member functions to this:

```
void __fastcall TfrmMain::Num1() { RunAs("first.exe"); }
void __fastcall TfrmMain::Num2() { RunAs("second.exe"); }
void __fastcall TfrmMain::Num3() { RunAs("third.exe"); }
```